# Modify line weights(stroke?)

Tags: vector, inkscape, dxf

Why, when I import a vector file (usually dxf), does it appear in Inkscape with large lineweights?

Comment: Dxf has technically no lineweights.

Comment: You can change the stroke width in Inkscape using the Fill and Stroke panel's [Stroke Style](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL_v16/html/Attributes-Stroke.html) tab.

Comment: @joojaa - whilst that's literally true in the CADD sense as there's no associated PC3, CTB or PMP files traveling with it, DXF does try to handle polyline width - I think the OP may be encountering polyline objects with set widths per drawn entity.